# How to disable FOREIGN KEY referential integrity trigger in PostgreSQL without disabling other triggers in table?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, foreign-key

FOREIGN KEYs referential integrity in PostgreSQL can be disabled by executing:

```sql
ALTER TABLE schema.my_table 
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

But unfortunately the command will also disable all other triggers present in the table.

I have tried locating the foreign key's name in `pg_constraint` view, but using it in the following command returns an error:

```sql
ALTER TABLE schema.my_table 
DISABLE TRIGGER id_fkey;

-- Returns
-- SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: trigger "id_fkey" for table "my_table" does not exist
```

How can referential integrity be disabled in PostgreSQL without disabling other triggers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you will have to find out the names of the system triggers on the table:

```
SELECT tgname,
       tgtype
FROM pg_trigger
WHERE tgrelid = 'myschema.mytable'::regclass
  AND tgisinternal;

            tgname            │ tgtype 
══════════════════════════════╪════════
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_25974 │      5
 RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_25975 │     17
(2 rows)
```

Then you have to disable these triggers:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable
   DISABLE TRIGGER "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_25974",
   DISABLE TRIGGER "RI_ConstraintTrigger_c_25975";
```

Note that disabling foreign keys might break your database.

Comment: thanks Laurenz! might break in what sense?

Comment: You could end up with foreign keys that are violated, so your data are inconsistent.